# Validation prevent check box to auto postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation

I have following checkboxes on my page:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="rbBuilding" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="HandlerPackageOnCheckedChanged" Checked="True" CausesValidation="False"   />
<asp:CheckBox ID="rbContent" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="HandlerPackageOnCheckedChanged" CausesValidation="False" />
```

There is an logic on postback based on combination of checkboxes clicked. Everything is working fine except one case:

I'm opening additional telerik radwindow which has some validation within its own validation group. If I close the window with any validation error, then the first click on any of that checkboxes 
does not do postpack.

Only FIRST click is not working. next time I click everything is working fine. I've tried to add check boxes to theirs own validation group and change casing validation to true. But behaviour is exactly the same. When I add test javascript method to onclick for that checkboxes then this method is fired without issue. There is just no postback.

I also tried to reset all validators for window validation group on window close, they are reset, but behaviour is not checking, and first click is not working.

**UPDATE**:

I've made one more check and realized it only happens if I do in javascript:

```
window.Page_ClientValidate("MyGroup")
```

Which I have to do before do some calculations on popup window. 
During dynamic validators, when updating validatable controls eveything is working properly, even if validation fails. So the problem is *Page_ClientValidate*

Comment: I believe I am running into the same issue. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: nope, I'm afraid not, and I didn't work on that project for 2 years now.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I did manage to resolve the issue and have posted the answer in case someone else stumbles across this as I did.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I ran into almost the exact issue and thanks to the following link I was able to resolve the issue:

[Issue with postbacks and clicking on controls twice](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/after-first-postback-why-i-have-to-click-the-button-twice-for-postback-to-occur)

I ended up adding this code to my code behind to add a javascript event handler for the checkbox's click event:

```
Checkbox1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "checkboxChanged();");
```

I then added the following javascript:

```
function checkboxChanged(arg1) {
  Page_BlockSubmit = false;
}
```

The checkbox in my situation was also set to have CausesValidation set to false but I don't think that's required for this fix. Hopefully this helps someone.